# How to filter questions on waiting time?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I was wondering if there is a way to filter questions on waiting time, i.e. searching for the oldest non-answered questions.
Is there an open database on Math SE which can be analyzed to get this kind of data?

Comment: The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) may be of interest.

Comment: ah wow! thanks!

Comment: If you want to find the oldest [unanswered questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unanswered-questions), you can simply view unanswered questions, sort them by newest and go to the last page: http://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest

Comment: Could you please clarify your question. The title is *average waiting time*, which suggests that you want to somehow calculate for how long a question remains unanswered. In the body of the question you ask how to find oldest unanswered questions. Those are two different questions.

Comment: @MartinSleziak you are right. I edited the title to extend the question to a broader class of queries.

Comment: Are you trying to look into how long questions take to get answered, or are you trying to look for what questions have been waiting the longest and are still waiting for an answer?

Comment: Both would be interesting. Arthur Fischer actually answered my question in the first comment, should I upgrade the comment to an answer?

Comment: I'd suggest that @Arthur should assume that honor, yeh.

Comment: Some related statistics: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12131/distribution-of-time-to-first-answer-in-mathstackexchange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) may be of interest for all<sup>*</sup> your Stack Exchange data exploring needs. Whether it be spelunking in the the comments, an archaeological dig through questions long since forgotten, or searching for [strange oddities](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/225495).

<sub>* (Well, not *all*. You won't be able to discover who has downvoted you... dag nab it!)</sub>

Comment: I don't get the oddity.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It's an *answer* with a *tag*, according to the database. An odd thing indeed, as if the request [About extending the tag system to answers, too](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16681/) was implemented. The tag does not show up on the site, since the page-building scripts take only pieces they need from the database.

Comment: @Thursday: Ah. That's as odd as putting 2 lumps of sugar in your beer (and who said that 2 is not an odd number? [of lumps of sugar in your beer])...